# One testing framework for several languages?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I'm currently running a project where we program in both Java, JavasSript and PHP.
Is it possible to write tests for the different pieces of the program/different langauges in the same language/framework? So that you can simply press Run on the tests once instead of installing three frameworks and running each of the frameworks once (once for Java, once for PHP and once for JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

One way would be to write a custom test driver for your testing framework of choice, which generates tests in the target language and runs them. I know of one company which did that for an embedded project. They wrote their tests in Ruby using the RSpec testing framework, but they actually replaced most of the RSpec machinery so that instead of running the tests *as-is* in Ruby, it would actually generate tests in C and run them against a mocked up version of their hardware, or even automatically upload them to the robot and run them there.

Another way would be to run all three languages on the same platform and use a testing framework for that platform. For example, you could run your PHP code on the JVM (using Quercus or P8) and your JavaScript code on the JVM (using dyn.js, Rhino or Nashorn) and then test all three using JUnit.